# Firebird - UTF8 VarChar size

Tags: utf-8, firebird, varchar

I am changing all varchar columns in our firebird database to UTF8 however I don't understand the difference in varchar size.

For example, with the charset and collation set to nothing, we can set the varchar size to 255, if we set the charset and collation to UTF8, when we set the varchar to 255, it reads different values.

What would be the equivalent varchar size for varchar(255) in UTF8?

Comment: What do you mean "it reads differente values?"

Answer (score 8):

Using the UTF8 character set for `VARCHAR(N)` fields needs to reserve enough space for any `N` UTF8 characters. The length of one such character may be between 1 and 4, so the only safe thing is to allow for `N` characters of length 4 each, meaning there needs to be space for 200 bytes to store the 50 characters (worst-case condition).

You could use the [FlameRobin](http://www.flamerobin.org) tool to have a look at the internals. Let's assume you have a table

```
CREATE TABLE "TableÅÄÖåäö"
(
  "ColÅÄÖåäö" Varchar(50)
);
```

in a database with default character set UTF8. (Note that you need at least Firebird 2.0 for this.)

The system tables store information about all relations and their fields. In the system table `RDB$RELATION_FIELDS` there is a record for this field, which has (for example) `RDB$1` as the `RDB$FIELD_SOURCE`. Looking into `RDB$FIELDS` there is one record for `RDB$1`, and its value of `RDB$FIELD_LENGTH` is 200.

So to answer your question: To have a UTF8 column with space for 255 characters you enter it as `VARCHAR(255)`, but in the database it will have a size of 1020 bytes.

Comment: Why is the size 1220 bytes? Should it be 255 * 4 = 1020 bytes?

Comment: @TomCat500: You are of course correct, a typo. Thanks for the hint, fixing it.